# Can you set more then one variable to one value

Tags: java

Can you set more then one variable to one value etc
Where you see n,n2 =3  i want to do something like that because i have many variables but its giving me an error

```
    int n,n2;
    int m,m2;

    n,n2 = 3
    m,m2 = 4
```

Comment: no, but you can go n = n2 = 3;

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202818/initializing-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   int n,n2,m,m2;

   n = n2 = 3;
   m = m2 = 4;
```