# how to declare multiple variables in one line in oracle plsql block

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

I want to declare multiple variable in one line, Is there any way to write it ?

```
DECLARE
A integer :=10;
B integer :=5;
BEGIN

END;
```

i want to declare a and b in one line.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: i have not come across this but it can be done using collection or record datatype

Comment: off topic, just curious here, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I, for one, would love to see this syntax (seen in some other languages) added to PL/SQL, e.g. `a, b, c, d, e integer;` although I'm not sure how defaults would work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No idea why you'd intentionally make your code less readable, but just... put them on one line:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  A integer :=10;B integer :=5;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(a ||':'|| b);
END;
/

anonymous block completed
10:5
```

The semicolon is a statement separator within PL/SQL and it doesn't matter whether or not you have whitespace or new lines; unlike plain SQL run in SQL*Plus, say, where a new statement after a separator does have to be on a new line, but that's a client thing.

Maybe you mean something else though...

Comment: Thanks for your help, But is there any better way for this ?

Comment: @AdarshPatel - better in what way? Are you asking to define two variables in one statement? That can't be done with scalar variables.

Comment: I think he was looking for something like this, but for PL/SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202818/initializing-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-java/31910261

Answer (score 6):

no, this is the way it works in PLSQL.