# initializing objects of same type simultaneously

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

Suppose I have A mutable class called `Person`.
What I want to do is to initialize several variables of `Person` at once.
Trying using

```
Person a,b,c,d;
a=b=c=d=new Person();
```

would necessarily point all of them to a same memory location.
How can I initialize them at once?  I don't want to use array or ArrayList.

Comment: This question can help you: [Initializing multiple variables to the same value in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202818/initializing-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-java)

Comment: Why don't you create an array of type `Person[]`. Then you can initialize them all in a loop.

Comment: @Blobonator I had seen that question already, but thought there might be a better way