# Does Java have multiple assignment as in Python?

Tags: java, python, variable-assignment

In Python

`a,b =b,a+b`

is there anything similar in Java?
I tried the same thing in Java but it didn't work.

Comment: So that answers your question

Comment: user7 hahahaha, maybe he is looking for another form of expression that works.

Comment: @AakashVerma You can find cheeky ways - But not anything like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not exactly. [Multiple assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8725673/1288) in Python does not work the same way in Java. In Java, if you [assign multiple variables at once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6202818/1288), you must be assigning them all to the *same value*.

To get similar behavior in Java, you'd have to encapsulate `a` and `b` in an object or other collection, then do the assignment based on setting/returning an object of that type. (Then there is the extra step of unpacking the values of `a` and `b` from that enclosing object or collection.)